# Cloudberry Backup "one or more backup paths don't exist"

Tags: cloudberry

This has been an issue plaguing me for a while but I finally decided to try and find the answer.

A couple of my backup plans always receive this warning "One or more backup paths don't exist". The reason for the warning seems to be because a folder/file that was there when the backup plan was created in no longer there. I get that. The problem is that I want to suppress these warnings. In my case (and I assume for others as well) the folder structure under the folder I am selecting to backup can change. Sub-folders and files can be added or removed. I was expecting Cloudberry to get the list of folders/files to backup at runtime and just back them up. It seems however that when the backup plan is created Clourberry traverses the folder structure and records all the folders/files and then attempts to backup each of them from the saved list.I believe it does pickup new folders and files but it does not seem to handle removed folders/files well (IMO).

Is there a way to suppress the warnings I am seeing? Otherwise, I basically get notification after each backup which tends to me just skipping the notification which could lead to me missing a notification I actually care about.

Comment: For me it's trying to re-add the files in the plan which don't exist anymore. I assume this is because they are still stored in the CloudBerry database...

Answer (score 0):

Our product does list backup source according to your selection in the backup plan, so the software has to check everything that you've pointed. In your case this might be irrelevant, but for many customers it is important to know what changed in the source and thus was not backed up.

As workaround I'd recommend you just to edit the plan and run through selections again from time to time to get rid of these warnings.

Comment: Where can I submit a feature request to have an option to ignore file/folder does not exist errors/warnings?

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress those warnings if you want as follows:

There is a way to suppress them by finding the .cbb file for that backup job.
To find the .cbb files do the following: Tools -> Diagnostics -> Open in Folder and go to the `CloudBerry Backup` folder that is one layer up. Usually at `C:\ProgramData\CloudBerryLab\CloudBerry Backup`

The .cbb files all have a rubbish name, so what I do is Edit the plan and save it again and then sort the folder by datetime. The first .cbb is the one you need.

Change the `<UseIgnoreErrorsOnPathNotFound>false</UseIgnoreErrorsOnPathNotFound>` line to `<UseIgnoreErrorsOnPathNotFound>true</UseIgnoreErrorsOnPathNotFound>` with the help of any text editor and save the file.